# date() function issue

Tags: date, timezone

I've created a WordPress website that based in Australia. I am having a problem with the `date()` function. The error message shown below. I have set the default timezone set to Australia/Melbourne, but I am still getting the error.

[image: error-message]

Answer (score 1):

How are you setting the timezone? If you're using the `date_default_timezone_set()` function, then you need to put this on every page of your website. The best way to do this on a WordPress website would be to add a line to `wp-config.php`:

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'Australia/Melbourne' );
```

However, the **best** way to set the default timezone is to add a line to `php.ini`:

```
date.timezone = Australia/Melbourne
```